# Search for files in OneDrive using Graph API endpoint broken

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm currently building an application to pull files from OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API.

There seems to a problem with the /drive endpoint when trying to make a search. To see the error, you can use the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) without logging in. Under sample queries, go to the OneDrive folder and choose "search my OneDrive". The result is a Bad Request - 400.

At first I thought I was making the bad request, but after trying with Microsoft's own sample query and sample data, I see that the problem goes a bit further.

How do we inform Microsoft? Is the problem definitely from them? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please try logging into the Graph explorer and hit https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='A') and see if you are able to get successful response. Because I was unable to repro the issue.

Comment: Yes i agree with Shiva. It works for me too. Either you can test in Graph explorer (make sure you login) or with POSTMAN and see if you can repro the issue or not.

Comment: thank you for the effort guys. I am now able to receive a successful response. I swear though, it wasn't working...

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/…. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Though technically it wasn't your answer which solved the problem. I think it was a bug that Microsoft eventually fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below call by logging into the Graph explorer.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='A')
```

In search method you can put any of your relevant driveItem names and see.

It worked for me.